# How to prevent user to subscribe twice to the same App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have following models.

I dont want that `User` can subscribe many times to the same `App`

So this shouldn`t be possible:

```
User.last.apps
=> [#<App id: 78, name: "Name">, #<App id: 78, name: "Name">]


User.last.subscriptions
=> [#<Subscription id: 78, app_id: 78>, #<Subscription id: 79, app_id: 78>]
```

**Models**

```
User
  has_many :subscriptions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :apps, through: :subscriptions

Subscription
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :app_id }
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
  belongs_to :app 

App  
  validates_uniqueness_of :name  
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
  belongs_to :app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added unique index to database in subscriptions table.

```
add_index :subscriptions, [:user_id, :app_id], unique: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a unique constraint to the association:

```
has_many :apps, through: :subscriptions, uniq: true
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would also prevent to have many subscription to the same app.